# Vector subscript out of range & standard c++ libraries out of range C++

Tags: c++, vector

```
void pathfind(const int* tiles, int startTile, int endTile, int height) {//const int* tiles is my map
int currentTile = startTile; //The spawn tile



    std::vector<int> points{ startTile };
    int i;//for loops
    bool possible = true;//to make sure they 



    if (tiles[currentTile + 1] <= 2 && floor(currentTile / height) == floor(currentTile - 1 / height)) {//Less than  2 because 3 and up are non-traverseable tiles.
        for (i = 1; i <= points.size(); i++) {

            if (points[i] == currentTile + 1) {
                possible = false;
            }

        }
        if (possible == true) {
            points.resize(points.size() + 1);
            points.at(points.size()) = currentTile + 1;
            currentTile++;
        }
    }
    else if (tiles[currentTile - 1] <= 2 && floor(currentTile / height) == floor(currentTile - 1 / height)) {
        for (i = 1; i <= points.size(); i++) {

            if (points[i] == currentTile - 1) {
                possible = false;
            }
            if (possible == true) {
                points.resize(points.size() + 1);
                points.at(points.size()) = currentTile - 1;
                currentTile--;
            }
        }

    }
    else if (tiles[currentTile - height] <= 2) {
        for (i = 1; i <= points.size(); i++) {

            if (points[i] == currentTile - height) {
                possible = false;
            }
            if (possible == true) {
                points.resize(points.size() + 1);
                points.at(points.size()) = currentTile - height;
                currentTile--;
            }
        }

    }
    else if (tiles[currentTile + height] <= 2) {
        for (i = 1; i <= points.size(); i++) {

            if (points[i] == currentTile + height) {
                possible = false;
            }
            if (possible == true) {
                points.resize(points.size() + 1);
                points[points.size()] = currentTile + height;
                currentTile--;
            }
        }

    }

    pointList = points;
}
```

This gives me a runtime error vector subscript out of range and then  if I ignore it then it says that the stand libraries are out of range and both these are on lines that aren't in the file.

And before this it gave me errors about using

```
 points.at[];
```

so when I removed those, these errors came.

Also I have sfml If that matters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if you are aware that vector/array indexes begin with 0. Seems your indexes always start with 1.

Comment: As @Shiping said indices start from 0 to length - 1.  `points.at(points.size())` must be `points.at(points.size() - 1)` and `i <= points.size()` must be `i < points.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ valid array's index (subscript) is in range [0, array_size-1]. So before accessing element of `tiles` or `points` make sure index is valid.

To add a new element to the end of vector use `push_back()` method: `points.push_back(currentTile - 1);`

Comment: so you _don't_ resize?

Comment: push_back() internally resizes by 1 and puts value at newly added location.